# Integral $\int_{1}^{2}x\left(mx^{\frac{1}{n}}-nx^{\frac{1}{m}}\right)^{-\frac{m+n}{m+n+2mn}}\left(x^{\frac{1}{m}}-x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Question:
Let, $\forall$ $m, n \in \text{R}$ three functions are defined by
$$f\left(m,n\right)=\int_{1}^{2}x\left(mx^{\frac{1}{n}}-nx^{\frac{1}{m}}\right)^{-\frac{m+n}{m+n+2mn}}\left(x^{\frac{1}{m}}-x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)dx$$
$$g_1(m,n)=f(m,1)-f(2,n)$$
and
$$g_2(m,n)=f(1,n)-f(m,2)$$
Then the value of
$$\lfloor g_1(2,3)+g_2(3,4)\rfloor$$

---

My Attempt:
$$g_1(2,3)+g_2(3,4)=f\left(2,1\right)+f\left(1,4\right)-f\left(2,3\right)-f\left(3,2\right)$$

Now numerically this value is equal to around $-0.45$, that would mean the answer is $-1$.

So I think it should be sufficient to prove that.  (Although this approach is considering we already know the answer).
$$-1\leq f\left(2,1\right)+f\left(1,4\right)-f\left(2,3\right)-f\left(3,2\right)<0$$

But I can't really understand how to tackle the original Integral.

My guess is we would have to use appropriate approximations?


Also we can see that $f(m,n)=f(n,m)$

Comment: Let $p(x)$ be the function inside the integral. For all $3$ cases $(m,n) = (1,2), (1,4), (2,3)$, we have $p(1)=0$, $p(x)$ is negative, concave and decreasing on $(1,2]$. So you could bound the integral by the areas of $2$ triangles as shown in [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/owl0bgpl5i). Namely, the green triangle has area $S_1$ and the blue $S_2$, so the integral $f(x)$ satisfies $S_2<=f(x)<=S_1$. The values of $S_1$ and $S_2$ can be obtained by calculating $f(2)$ and $f'(1)$.

Comment: @MengchunZhang Thank you for the comment! Though I do believe there to be an alternate solution as this was given in a mock test for a certain exam, to be solved within 6 minutes (no calculators).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In this case, I believe an alternative approach has to be used since the calculation for $S_1$ and $S_2$ could be quite heavy without calculators.